# Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 error clang

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4, llvm, building

Sorry my English is bad, i'm French.

I'm starting in the C language and I meet an error during my building

```
error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I try to find some solution on the web, but no result..

```
ProcessPCH /Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/DevTool-Prefix-btzmnprddvcwlhbcsotsvtjgrmyp/DevTool-Prefix.pch.pth DevTool/DevTool-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/Hollisprice/Documents/xCode/DevTool
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -iquote /Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/DevTool.build/Debug/DevTool.build/DevTool-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/DevTool.build/Debug/DevTool.build/DevTool-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/DevTool.build/Debug/DevTool.build/DevTool-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/DevTool.build/Debug/DevTool.build/DevTool-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -I/Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/DevTool.build/Debug/DevTool.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/DevTool.build/Debug/DevTool.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/DevTool-Prefix-btzmnprddvcwlhbcsotsvtjgrmyp/DevTool-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/Hollisprice/Documents/xCode/DevTool/DevTool/DevTool-Prefix.pch -o /Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/DevTool-Prefix-btzmnprddvcwlhbcsotsvtjgrmyp/DevTool-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Hollisprice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevTool-dfnxafkbvghokwdpcwpuvrurijwt/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/DevTool-Prefix-btzmnprddvcwlhbcsotsvtjgrmyp/DevTool-Prefix.pch.d
```

Thank's to help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that happens because you are compiling code with ARC for 32-bit x86. You must compile to 64-bit architecture if you want to use ARC.